# Is there any Google Adsense revenue if a visitor rolls over (hovers) on an ad unit?

Tags: google, google-adsense, google-ads, revenue

I have noticed an increase in interactive flash animations especilly on 300px wide adsense ads. Many of them ask the visitor to rollover to either reveal what the ad is about, show a clip, etc.

So I wonder: the visitor is giving attention to this ad, is viewing its message -- ***without clicking on it***.

In essence, the ad agency's objective is accomplished without a click, which would be a significant money saver if PPC is considered. This seems very ingenious on their part, and I wonder how this is handled by Google. Shouldn't there be a fee for a publisher if visitors interact with ads, regardless of clicks? CTR becomes irrelevant in this context.

Are you aware of anything being discussed in this respect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be just counted as a single ad view, no doubt the CPM rates would be higher for such ads. You will be paid according to the CPM rate as per my knowledge if the user hasn't clicked on those ads.

Comment: thx @jigar - do you think that is fair to the publisher? (I'm undecided FWIW)

Comment: Yes i do agree with you @torr. But I believe that even though we don't get paid equal to CPC on rollover, but it should be higher than CPM.